# Explicit object casting in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, casting

I'm relatively new to Java, thus the question. Why does Java cast objects and what exactly goes on with the compiler when an object is being cast. This is my code for a simple level order search.

```
void LevelOrder(Node root)
    {
       Queue<Node> Q = new LinkedList();
       Q.add(root);
       while(!Q.isEmpty()){
           Node p = Q.poll();
           System.out.print(p.data+ " ");
           if(p.left != null) Q.add(p.left);
           if(p.right != null) Q.add(p.right);
       }


    }
```

When I run this code on a web-based IDE provided by hacker rank it compiles but gives me the following warning.

```
Note: Solution.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

When I cast the node object by changing the line of `poll` to this,

```
Node p = (Node)Q.poll();
```

It still compiles showing the same warning.

However on my IntelliJ IDE the first code wouldn't even compile and only the second one(with the explicit cast) compiles.

Can someone explain what's going on here exactly.
Aside from resolving the error can someone please explain why one compiler lets this line compile, whereas the other doesn't without explicit casting.

```
Node p = Q.poll();
```

Comment: You need `<>` after `LinkedList`, i.e. `LinkedList<>`.

Comment: you need to read up on generics

Comment: Why the down vote. If everyone in the world knew everything there would be no SO.

Comment: I did not downvote, but SO expects that your read first the manual, This topic is well described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new LinkedList();
```

This is a [raw-typed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) collection - the compiler doesn't know what type of elements are in it (even though there is actually *nothing* in it).

As such, when you try to assign it to a reference which can only contain elements of type `Node`:

```
Queue<Node> Q = new LinkedList();
```

then the compiler can't know whether that is safe or not.

The fix is simple: tell the compiler the type of the elements:

```
Queue<Node> Q = new LinkedList<Node>();
```

It can be even simpler in Java 7+:

```
Queue<Node> Q = new LinkedList<>();
```

In this case, the compiler infers the type as `<Node>`. The `<>` is known as "diamond notation"; it can't be used in all cases, but can be used in an assignment context like this.

Comment: I've slightly updated my question, could you update your answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see the edit history in the android app - what is the change?

Comment: The web based IDE lets the line without the explicit cast compile while IntelliJ doesn't. That's the part that's still unanswered. Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the two compilers, it's hard to say anything other than "they are different compilers, and handle raw types differently". Maybe there is some latitude in JLS around how raw types are handled; maybe they are different Java versions etc. Sorry, I can't give you a definitive answer without more information (and more knowledge on my part).

Answer (score 1):

The cause is this line:

```
Queue<Node> Q = new LinkedList();
```

if you change it to

```
Queue<Node> Q = new LinkedList<Node>();
```

the warning disapers.

In the first case you have a list of `Object`,
in the second a list of `Node`.

This is mostly relevant at compile time. Later during execution all Collections are of type Object. If you feed in objects of other types into the list, you would get at runtime an ClassCastException. (In cases the compiler cannot detect that you add objects of wrong type)

Since java 1.7 it's possible to just write

```
Queue<Node> Q = new LinkedList<>();
```

The compiler is now clever enough to know that you mean `Node`.

Answer (score 1):

Fix this line with adding `<>` after declaring a LinkedList like here:

```
Queue<Node> Q = new LinkedList<>();
```

Or you can also do like here:

```
Queue<Node> Q = new LinkedList<Node>();
```

Note that the diamond operator in JDK 7 can be used instead of explicit type parameters. So I prefer the first way.